# a simple way to add or modify glyphs in true type fonts (TTF)

Tags: c#, c++, truetype

I'm looking for a simple way to add a glyph to an existing true type font. I'm wondering if there exists a library (C++ or C#) or a command line tool to support that functionality because generating a TTF from scratch seems to be a really complex task.
The background for this question is that we would like to develop a tool that is able to add a glyph to a font. The glyph would be defined as an outline consisting of multiple contours  that are consisting of lists of points (on curve and off curve).

Comment: If you added a glyph to an existing TTF, it could no longer be the same TTF. For example, if someone were to change one of the fonts in the Times New Roman character set to something else, anyone using the computer would have a messed up font. Because of this, I would have to guess that existing fonts are not editable. Maybe you should look into creating a new font that starts by copying the information from the font you want to default to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, I have not seen such a commandline tool/library.

Generating a font may be complex but modifying an existing font can be just as bad.

When you add a glyph to an existing font, you will need to specify additional things along with it( e.g. unique character code, metrics values, etc). Furthermore you will also need to update quite a few tables in the font file(eg cmap, loca, maxp, etc), depending on the nature of new outline.

Basically I don't think there is a simple way to add a glyph.

The best thing I can think of is to use a font editor tool to add your glyphs/create a new font (e.g. FontForge http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score -6):

You basically cannot do this (except with some open-licenced fonts which allow derivative works).

This is not because it is impossible, but because it is illegal. Fonts are copyright.

I suggest you find another way to solve whatever problem prompted the question.

Comment: If the font is on the end users system, they're generally licenced to use it. How it's used or bundled may have some legal implications but not in all cases. Regardless, that's beside the point; it was a technical question not a legal question.